# Prestashop 1.6 CategoryController.php assignProductList function is really slow, how could I track the SQL queries?

Tags: prestashop-1.6

I migrate my Prestashop 1.6 e-commerce to another server and I do not know why but is painfull slow. I find that this method is where is the problem

```
public function assignProductList()
```

In the file CategoryController.php
Exactly this line

```
 $this->cat_products = $this->category->getProducts($this->context->language->id, (int)$this->p, (int)$this->n, $this->orderBy, $this->orderWay);
```

How can I track this code for debugging, I have no idea what is calling and where.
Thanks in advance.

Thanks in advance, sorry for my english.

Comment: You can enable profiler and check

Comment: Watch executed query on getProducts , maybe in server migration table indexes were not replicated.